# How to checkout a release with go get?

Tags: git, go

I have been trying to install a module using `go get github.com/xxx/xxx`. It used to get installed easily previously, but the maintainers release a new release and it's not working for me anymore. I am looking to know if there is any way I can get the previous release to install? By default it is installing the master branch. Is there any flag where I can put the branch info like `go get github.com/xxx/xxx --branch=xxx`?

Comment: A short term solution is to just go into the relevant GitHub repository directory and directly issue the relevant `git` commands to change to whatever revision you wish. Unless you use `go get -u` (which tries to update to the latest version), the Go tools will leave it at the revision you manually selected.

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll need to use an external dependency management tool that can handle branch and version freezes. Then you use it instead of calling `go get` directly - this changes from tool to tool - and you can freeze versions. A few popular tools:

1. Godep (I personally use it): https://github.com/tools/godep
2. Nut https://github.com/jingweno/nut
3. Gopm https://github.com/gpmgo/gopm
4. Some libraries use `gopkg.in` which embeds vesions into the import urls. http://labix.org/gopkg.in *This does allow to use go-get directly, but it depends on whether the libraries are released via gopkg*

Answer (score 1):

You can fork the library and decide if you want to pull new versions to your fork. And roll back if the new version break you application.